# TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'str', help me

Tags: python-3.x, k-means

```
    TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
    <ipython-input-57-9923ccb36c50> in <module>
          1 # Menghitung centroid terhadap setiap data
    ----> 2 get_centroids = findClosestCentroids(centroids, X)
          3 get_centroids
    
    <ipython-input-56-e0c7686644a5> in findClosestCentroids(ic, X)
          5         distance=[]
          6         for j in ic:
    ----> 7             distance.append(calc_distance(i, j))
          8         assigned_centroid.append(np.argmin(distance))
          9     return assigned_centroid
    
    <ipython-input-55-3794b807a3d1> in calc_distance(X1, X2)
      1 # Menghitung jarak antar dua data
      2 def calc_distance(X1, X2):
----> 3     return(sum((X1 - X2)**2))**0.5

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'str'
```

Please help me where I'm wrong..

Answer (score 0):

it looks like X1 and X2 in calc_distance are strings, the error message is saying that you cannot subtract a string from another string. You'll have to go back to your inputs and make sure that the centroids are the correct type.